# How to get a set of unique Integers if I have a set of unique Longs?

Tags: java, casting, primitive

I hava a set of `Longs` (`Timestamps` actually). Apparently they can't be casted to `Integers` without loosing data because the `timestamp` doesn't fit `Integer` range. I need to generate a Primary Key of `Integer` type based on these `Longs`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would it hurt to trucate the timestamps? What's their precision? Seconds? Milliseconds?

Comment: The only general answer to this is to use a lookup table (or perfect hash)...

Comment: And why do you need primary keys of type integer?

Comment: Knowing the time range of these timestamps, you could use the modulo value.

Comment: Milliseconds. Truncation doesn't fit my task because I can get a couple of not unique PK's. The same is with simple casting - I can get a negative Integer.

Comment: `SL` is set of all long and `SI` is set of all integer you can never achieve one to one mapping from `Sl` to `SI` that will contain all elements in `SL`.

Comment: I'm inserting data through a not modifiable web service, so I have to deal with Integers.

Comment: Generally, you want primary keys to be as meaningless as possible, just a unique identifier to distinguish between different values, so I would recommend not basing them on actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the range of date timestamps are created is limited. Let's say dates after December, 12 2004. Seems like a reasonable approach truncating the highest significant digits, e.g.

```
long 00001357288262
int      1357288262
```

Comment: I guess this is a suitable workaround for my situation. Thank for idea!

Comment: Won't this generate collisions after just 24 days?

Comment: @Keppil I believe it's 49.7 days as you can get negative numbers but they won't collide.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are more `Long`s than `Integer`s, there is no safe way to do this that will work for all set of `Long`s.
However, if the `Long`s are not too far apart, you might be able to take use the first timestamp as 0, ad then just use the difference to get a unique `Integer` for each subsequent timestamp.

Comment: It's a sort of a problem for me to store this information between two launches of my application. That's why timestamps were chosen as PK's.

Comment: If you hardcode a starting point and truncate the milliseconds, this approach won't generate any duplicates for around 70 years, which might be ok.

Comment: Or even more than 135 years, since negative numbers will also not produce duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

There lots of ways, but do you really think that primary key based on timestamp is a good idea? It is not so hard to have several entries with same timestamp so it is not going to be a really good key.

Anyway, since you are using java, I guess your Timestamps are in milliseconds. Since truncation it to seconds is totally bad idea (it is very easy to get collision with other entries in same second) probably good idea will be to 'shift' timestamps: choose minimum date from timestamps and make that zero timestamp, and others relative to it: in this case you will probably fit into integer.

Comment: As I commented in upper answer it's a sort of a problem for me to store this information between two launches of my application. But during its one launch I can store all already generated int's and compare all new with them? to avoid duplication. So I guess the answer of Boris Pavlović is the closest to my situation.